# Firebase takes too much time to save data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a simple JSON structure in Firebase console. I have a kind of chat app that uses this data to chat with other users. Everything works fine. But just sometimes, even after [adding the value to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) with `setValue`, I cannot see the value in the console for a very long time(like around 3-5 mins).

For example:[image: JSON structure on firebase]

For the above structure, I am adding values with below code snippet:

```
mFirebaseTyping.child("68_118").child("118").setValue(typingObject)
```

Now, it takes too long to update value to firebase. Sometimes around 3-5 minutes.

Does anyone have any work around this lagging issue? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: I tried with [CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) too, but the response only takes that time(i.e.: 3-5 mins). So does that mean this [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) is not recommended for chatting apps?

Comment: This is happening every time you want to set a value?

Comment: No, that's the weirdest thing. It only happens sometimes. In a period of few hours on some day. After that everything works as wanted.

Comment: The code you shared looks fine, and is not likely to be the cause of this problem. If your data is not showing in the console, it is most likely that it never made it to the Firebase server. The fact that your completion listener fires at the same time seems to confirm that. It is hard to say where the data gets stuck. Does this just happen when writing? Or is reading equally delayed?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, only sometimes.

Comment: That makes it very hard to speculate beyond the fact that the connection between the device and the servers is likely lost. You could enable debug logging to see what that says. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)